# Minecraft modsauce under AT-Launcher is throwing Warnings

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I have AT-Launcher based Minecraft (1.7.1) installed.   With it I have the HermitModSauce Pack installed with every mod it comes with.  I am using this with Ubuntu and Java version 7 under OpenJDK.

```
[13/12/2014 13:26:25 PM] [Client thread/ERROR] [FML]: FML has detected a mod that is using a package name based on 'net.minecraft.src' : net.minecraft.src.Start. This is generally a severe programming error.  There should be no mod code in the minecraft namespace. MOVE YOUR MOD! If you're in eclipse, select your source code and 'refactor' it into a new package. Go on. DO IT NOW!
```

This is one of them, why does this get thrown?

```
[13/12/2014 13:27:04 PM] [Client thread/WARN] [FML]: * Illegal extra prefix advGen for name advGen:dnaanalyser, invalid registry invocation/invalid name?
[13/12/2014 13:27:04 PM] [Client thread/WARN] [FML]: *  at cpw.mods.fml.common.registry.GameData.registerItem(GameData.java:755)
[13/12/2014 13:27:04 PM] [Client thread/WARN] [FML]: *  at cpw.mods.fml.common.registry.GameRegistry.registerBlock(GameRegistry.java:215)
[13/12/2014 13:27:04 PM] [Client thread/WARN] [FML]: *  at cpw.mods.fml.common.registry.GameRegistry.registerBlock(GameRegistry.java:171)
[13/12/2014 13:27:04 PM] [Client thread/WARN] [FML]: *  at cpw.mods.fml.common.registry.GameRegistry.registerBlock(GameRegistry.java:160)
[13/12/2014 13:27:04 PM] [Client thread/WARN] [FML]: *  at com.advGenetics.Proxy.CommonProxy.registerBlock(CommonProxy.java:19)
[13/12/2014 13:27:04 PM] [Client thread/WARN] [FML]: *  at com.advGenetics.AdvGenetics.preLoad(AdvGenetics.java:333)...
[13/12/2014 13:27:04 PM] [Client thread/WARN] [FML]:
```

What prefix is it talking about?  This action duplicates 7 times before moving on.

```
[13/12/2014 13:27:54 PM] [Client thread/WARN] [FML]: Unable to lookup CompactMachines:personalShrinkingDevice for public static org.dave.CompactMachines.item.ItemPersonalShrinkingDevice org.dave.CompactMachines.init.ModItems.personalShrinkingDevice. Is there something wrong with the registry?
```

Problem with the registry?  I havent found any.  This also happens with 8 other objects when checked against.

This url is the full log if needed.
http://www.filedropper.com/untitleddocument1

Comment: full log url is dead.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about support for a modded version of Minecraft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forge and Minecraft are a bit... talkative, they often show a lot of debug log information to the user that only developers need to worry about, these are all examples of that.

The first one is a mod developer being dumb and placing the code they've written in the wrong folder, this is a bad thing because if multiple mods have the exact same class name the game won't run (after all, the game is trying to call a thing by name, but two things would respond, the computer can't know which you want). Given that only one mod is giving the error (unfortunately it doesn't say which) this is nothing to worry about, you'd notice if there was a problem (the game wouldn't start).

There is nothing you can do about this, that's for the mod developer to fix, just ignore it.

The second one is talking about the item registry, a huge list where all the items are stored. The mod prefix is automatically added when registering, but the mod author manually added it as well, nothing to worry about, other mods just need to use advGen:advGen:dnaanalyser if they want to reference it by name, which is dumb.

The third one is still talking about the item registry, the mod Compact Machines (great mod by the way :D!) is probably doing something wrong when telling the game about its items, not a problem as such, just makes it harder for other modders to do something with them, not a problem for users either.

So in short, lots of information that is useful for the developers of the mods in question, but none of them are a problem for you. In fact, I'm using those mods as well and getting the same error and nothing bad is happening (well, nothing bad that I didn't cause :) ).